# How to set/get the highlighted item in GridView?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

Working on a WinUI app that uses GridView to show a collection of images.

Trying to figure out how to get / set the item that is currently highlighted by keyboard navigation.

I see that when I select an item with the mouse, a bunch of Clicked and Tapped events are fired on the child item and the 'selected' item is also available through SelectedItem, SelectedIndex in the GridView control. But if I use the keyboard to move between items, I could not find any events that get fired and any way to query the Gridview which item is 'highlighted'.

The highlighting vs selection difference in GridView is driving me a bit nuts.

In the snapshot below, the first item is highlighted through keyboard navigation, but the 2nd item is returned as selected.

[image]

```
   <GridView x:Name="ImageGridView"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTemplate}"
              SelectionMode="Single"/>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate"
                x:DataType="local:Item">
       <StackPanel 
           IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
           DoubleTapped="ImageDoubleTapped"
           IsTapEnabled="True"
           Tapped="ImageTapped"
           GotFocus="Panel_GotFocus">
            <Grid><Image/></Grid>
      </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

New to WinUI programming. Looked through the MSDN documentation for GridView and WinUI quite extensively over upwards of 8 hours but not seeing a solution. Tried looking through LiveTree view and property values to find something relevant. Tried a bunch of event handlers tapped, click etc but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

OMG. I think I may have found the solution one minute after posting the question as I was closing my research tabs.

```
<GridView x:Name="ImageGridView"
      **SelectionChanged="ImageGridView_SelectionChanged"**
      ...
```

Comment: Still, it is very important what is your data source.  Is it `ObservableCollection<T>`?